# Autohotkey Send method not working

Tags: autohotkey

So I made a git repository were I versionned all my mods installation, what I want to do is make a script which loads every revision one by one then for each revision loads every save one by one and take a screenshot.

However I'm having problem communicating with the git bash.
this code :

```
#SingleInstance Force
#Persistent
#UseHook

Home::
revision := "a65d52958af020caa42e2243ec466d14b6cf2689"
loadRevision(revision)
Return

loadRevision(revision) {
    Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" "--login" "-i"
    Sleep 1000
    Send cd{Space}C:`\Program{Space}Files{Space}(x86)`\The{Space}Elder{Space}Scrolls{Space}V{Space}Skyrim
    sleep 200
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep 200
    Send git{Space}checkout{Space}%revision%
    Sleep 200
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep 120000
    IfWinExist, "Git Bash"
        WinClose
}
```

is producing this result :

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91396766/ahk.PNG

Any idea why? 
I'm using a French windows 7 X64 and I have an AZERTY keyboard.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do this via AutoHotkey rather than a shell script? Isn't the whole point of Git Bash that you're able to run bash scripts?

Comment: lauch git bash>Load revision i>close git bash>lauch skyrim>load all save one by one while taking screenshot>close skyrim>i++>go back to start

Comment: I think it will be a lot easier to manage with autohotkey

Comment: Oh, ye gods, I didn't realize you were trying to drive Skyrim with it. Best of luck with that.

Comment: Actually I already wrote the code driving skyrim, and now that I think about it, I don't have this problem in the skyrim console, 9=9, (=(, etc.

Comment: Perhaps you could write a simple bash script to load a given revision from Git, and then, instead of trying to send keys to bash from the AutoHotkey script, just launch an instance of Git Bash with the revision-loading script as a command line argument.